# GIS & ASP.NET displaying shapefiles in the asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, esri

I want to display esri shapefiles into my asp.net web application, the shape files need to be themed.
e.g i have on district layer having 22 districts along with the poulation field in the district laye. i want each polygon to have a label showing district name and along with the population of the district. 
i should be able to pan zoom etc also when i click each polygon theattribute should get displayed in the form of a popup. 
also i should be able to overlay more than one layers and use checkbox to select or unselect layers.

i have read about shaprmap, easygis.net but i cant figure out any working code to start with.

all help appreciateed. 
the application doenst store data in the database

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should explore Esri's offerings for .NET SDK. If it's anything as good as their javascript API, I'd say it'd be worth looking into. I know they support displaying maps from geoJSON as well as from their own servers.

If you're hosting your own app then the use of their API's and SDKS is free.
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/

Comment: I have read about it but there are nothing for web. It's for wpf mainly using silverlight..

Comment: I know that there's a silverlight API offered by Esri although you might have to do some extra digging as it's considered legacy now. I'm currently writing a new application to replace our old silverlight viewer that used the silverlight API.

https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/